# How do I get functions defined outside of a canvas draw loop to be useable within the loop?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I can't get this simple thing to work.

I'm defining a function before I enter the draw loop. But it won't work.
Put the code from the function directly into the loop and it works like a charm. How do I get the function defined outside of the draw loop to work within it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="draw();">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            setInterval(draw,120);
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');


            var dot = function(px,py) {
            fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            ctx.fillRect(px,py,12,12)
            };

            function draw() {
                if (canvas.getContext) {
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    dot(34,34);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pass `ctx` as a parameter to `dot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define it outside of draw the ctx you are using is different because of js' scoping rules. What you should do is pass the context into the function.

```
    var dot = function(ctx,px,py) {
        fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect(px,py,12,12)
    };

        function draw() {
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                dot(ctx,34,34);
            }
        }
```

Another thing you could consider is to make the context a global variable like the canvas since you will be using it a lot.

```
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var dot = function(px,py) {
        fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect(px,py,12,12)
     };

        function draw() {
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                dot(34,34);
            }
        }
```